# Is there a way in flask-sqlalchemy to drop or create a single table?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In regular sqlalchemy there is an option to drop or create a single file. [source](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#creating-and-dropping-database-tables)
`employees.drop(engine)`

However in flask_sqlalchemy there is only `create_all()` and `drop_all()`.
I cannot figure out how to drop or create an individual table in the documentations.
I have tried the following:

- looking at the flask_sqlalchemy SQLALCHEMY definitions. No luck finding `drop` or `create`.
- passing a table list to the flask-sqlalchemy SQLALCHEMY instance. Got a unexpected keyword argument.
- Googling/SO but very few resources. Or maybe I'm not looking in the right place.

Surely the flask-sqlalchemy has a way to do something basic like drop a single table. Right?
Or would I have to run raw sql queries to drop a single table?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still looking for this:

```
User.__table__.drop(db.engine)
```

That's it!